# Equally distribute values across multiple sets

Tags: ms-access, vba

### Background/context:

I have a table containing a listing of schools, each having a geographic region and a number of students to be contacted:

```
school_id, region, student_count
1, West, 23
2, Central, 33
3, East, 55
4, West, 7
5, West, 18
6, Central, 45
7, Central, 15
8, West, 32
Etc.
Etc… (there are ~1500 schools)
```

- All schools are to be assigned to a group of support staff that will send out letters to the students at each school.
- The distribution of schools (by region) and student count (for all schools) has to be divided as equally as possible.  That is to say, if there are 5 support staff, the division of schools by region and student count should be (as close to) equal as possible for each staff person.  That said, the overall number of schools per region and student count will vary, i.e., the number of regions and student counts will never been equally divisible.

### Specific problem:

I assumed the solution would require dividing up the schools by region (into lists), and then the values from them would be divided among the support staff members. The end result would be written to a table called `staff_assignment`:

```
staff_id, school_id
1, 1
1, 6
1, 3
2, 8
2, 7
2, 4
Etc.
Etc…
```

So, **I need to equally distribute 3 lists of values amongst n sets.**  The distribution of the 3 lists needs to be (as close to) equal
for both the number of items being distributed as well as the overall total values for each set.  For example:

```
List 1 [27, 55, 34, 15, 8, 22, 17, 9, 13, 5, 25, 16, 36, 6, 17, 26, 37]
List 2 [10, 32, 46, 24, 19, 23, 14, 51, 41, 12, 18, 64, 9, 11]
List 3 [11, 49, 30, 29, 25, 20, 9, 13, 50, 12, 32, 39, 18, 12, 21, 33, 20, 15, 23, 11]

would be distributed amongst (in this case) 5 sets as:

Set 1 [L1.27, L2.24, L3.25, etc., etc.]
Set 2 [L1.55, L2.64, L3.49, etc., etc.]
Set 3 [L1.34, L2.32, L3.33, etc., etc.]
Set 4 [L1.15, L2.14, L3.15, etc., etc.]
Set 5 [L1.8, L2.9, L3.9, etc.,etc.]
```

I am implementing this via an MS Access Form, so the solution will be done using VBA (the list values and number of sets for distribution will be obtained from user input via the Form).

I have searched this site and the Net and there are some solutions, but they are all for other programming languages (e.g., C++, Ruby) that I have no experience with (I'm an in-house 'resource' who knows just enough to be the one who gets asked to concoct solutions to this kind of stuff). So, I just hoped there may a Black Belt VBA guru here that couyld explain how to do the same in VBA.

Comment: What is the source of your input? Natively, there is no *list* or *set* structure in VBA. And why MS Access? Do you need storage in a database? Please give full context of your problem as this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Can you insert all of the values from all the lists into a one column table then run a query on that table sorting by the column then divide that record set into n sections? Am I over-simplifying the problem?

Comment: Hi Parfait.  Thanks for following up (again).  I'm using MS Access because I require a GUI, tables and reports (which I'm familiar with in MS Access).  I hope my edit provides proper context.

Comment: Hi Tony. Thank you for your response.  Given that the numbers of schools by region and overall student counts are not equal, I believe it's a more complex solution (if everything was equal, then I think your solution would work; sort and divide by the number of staff).

Comment: This is an interesting problem. So there are roughly 1500 schools, each with `n` number of students. Is the region important? What do you think happens if you sum `n` and divide by the number of staff, then sort the entire list of schools descending and iterate through that list assigning that school to the staff member with the fewest students assigned? Once a staff member hits the `n/staff` number then that staff member is removed from the list of staff members accepting new students. I'm just spitballing here.

Comment: Hi Tony.  Thanks for taking the time to consider this problem.  Yes, the Region component also has to be (as close as possible) equally divided, which is what makes (for me) a complex problem.  I've been reading various posts and this seems to be akin to what is referred to as a 'bin sorting' problem, however, that's one dimensional (equally distributing a one quantity into bins) where as I have two dimensions to be equally distributed (number of schools by region and overall student counts).

Comment: There are repeating values in your sample lists. Is this normal?

Comment: Hi Ivan.  Yes, the number of students can be the same (schools are unique, the number of students is not).

Comment: Dave, did you get this solved? Are you still working on it? Just thinking through it I think the key points are creating a greedy algorithm that leverages the ability of Access to mimic complex data structures with tables and queries. It appears that the regions can be split, in other words more than one staff member can have schools from the West region. If that is the case then I still think it is a case of ordering the first table by student count descending then picking an arbitrary starting staff member and giving them the school-region combination with the highest count.

Comment: After that then use the school count, region count, and student count to pick the next staff member. You will have to set a priority on the three counts when determining the next staff member and pick an arbitrary one in the event of a tie.

Comment: Hi Tony.  Thanks for your response.  As of yesterday, I have pieced together a solution (it's not very elegant) that seems to work.  I have to spend a bit of time testing it and I'll post the solution when I'm done.  Again, thank you for your time and effort.  Dave